# an example for 2d vector shape editor in winform

Tags: .net, winforms, vector-graphics

I want to implement a simple 2d vector shaper editor in winform, can anyone give a startup project for reference? 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know, but these links maybe help you :
[Simple Vector Shape](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19195/Simple-Vector-Shapes)
and ["SvgPad"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8207/SVGPad-Application-and-class-library-for-editing-S) and ["A C# SVG rendering engine"](http://svg.codeplex.com/)

and if you are going to build a vector graphic editor look at these:
 ["An SVG framework in C# and an SVG-GDI+ bridge"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3751/An-SVG-framework-in-C-and-an-SVG-GDI-bridge)
and 
["SvgNET"](https://github.com/monoman/SvgNet)
["Gtk Sharp"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gtk_Sharp)

also there are many open source project for vector graphic editing, like :["VRR"](http://atrey.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/projekty/vrr/index.html)

good luck